# Magento cron jobs not getting scheduled

Tags: magento-1.8, cron

I just truncated the cron_schedule table.After that jobs are not getting scheduled.The table is always empty.Any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you figured it out? I am also facing the same problem. I have even tried manualy generating schedule using Aoe_scheduler but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

You did do the obvious check that cron is enabled in the host?

example logged in via ssh as the webuser you can do:

```
crontab -l
```

which will list the crons for the web user

```
*/5 * * * * /home/website/public_html/cron.sh
```

Did you check the server error logs (cron logs in /var/log) for any errors?

```
cat /var/log/cron
```

Have you tried running through all this setup, and make sure it is all setup correctly? http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

in some instances/servers calling the cron.php / cron.sh from crontab does not work due to permission errors. You can then use wget/curl to call the cron.php file via the web url as such:

```
*/5 * * * * curl -s -o /dev/null http://www.yoursite.com/absolute/path/to/magento/cron.php
```

If your crontab is configured, try that approach, maybe it will work for you.

also install the great module called [Aoe_scheduler](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-cron-scheduler.html) - it is a better way to manage your crons in Magento

Comment: cron was working before i truncated the cron_schedule table

Comment: Interesting. Anything in the logs? I highly suggest you try the scheduler module, it will give you a clear view  what the cron subsystem in magento is up to.

Comment: Nothing in the magento exception log either.I will try using AOE scheduler